# How to keep only numbers using python

Tags: python

I want to keep only numbers and remove all other characters and alphanumeric values from dataset

```
names = [ ["cat", 911, "dog123", 562], ["luck", 123, "bad23"] ]

expected output : [ [911, 562], [123] ]
```

Comment: `[[x for x in y if isinstance(x, int)] for y in names]`?

Comment: In Python, it is not healthy to change a list you are working on. It is customary to create a new list applying some filtering condition